# How to import svg saved as js file in react

Tags: reactjs

the js file like

```
import React from "react";

export default () => (
  <svg
    className="xxx"
    data-testid="ggg"
    width="20"
    height="20"
    viewBox="0 0 20 20"
    fill="none"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  >
    <path
      d="xxxx"        />
  </svg>
);
```

how to import this and used in other components?

Answer (score 1):

Its a normal component:

```
import MySvg from 'path/to/svg'

<MySvg />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should name your component like

```
import React from "react";

export class SvgIcon extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
  <svg
    className="xxx"
    data-testid="ggg"
    width="20"
    height="20"
    viewBox="0 0 20 20"
    fill="none"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  >
    <path d="xxxx"/>
  </svg>
    )
  }
}
```

And now you can use it:

```
<SvgIcon/>
```

Don't forget import component

```
import SvgIcon from "*component path*";
```